# client-side validation and client-side form validation

Tags: forms, validation

When I looked into client-side validation I found the term "client-side form validation", and it was described somewhat similar as client-side validation. My question is, if these terms are interchangeably, or if they have different meanings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side form validation specifically refers to validation of forms. Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Client side validation refers to validating data on client side not specifically forms. It can be any type of validation such as clicking links which a user is not supposed to click or accessing unauthorized part of the website/app or even validating user input via form (which is client-side form validation)